How can God not be a magician if Jesus' conception was supernatural?
To create more humans a member of the female sex has to copulate with a member of the male sex.  The man's sperm fertilities the egg and an embryo develops in the females womb and this is natural.
I do not know how each denomination interprets Mary's virgin birth within the Christian faith. If Mary gave birth to Jesus as a virgin how can this not be considered supernatural as well as in the realm of magic?  But the Catholic Pope Francis said that the Christian God is not a magician.  There are also examples of testimony that Jesus performed miracles outside of the natural order.
I know I have asked a similar question about God's omnipotence but these testimonies come into conflict with the Catholic Church's position upon the power of God.  My intention is not to criticize the Christian faith at all.  On the other hand, these questions come out of respect for the existence of God.
So are there denominations of the Christian Faith that still believe that God has unquestionable power?

This question doesn't really seem to be about the theology of the virgin birth, but instead what Pope Francis said. Can you please [edit] this to give a full quotation of what he said?

"Pope Francis said that the Christian God is not a magician" — He obviously had a different definition of "magician" in mind than you or I have. Without knowing what that definition is, the question can't really be answered.

Select a definition for magician that corresponds with your concept of one.  That will make it simple to answer.

A magician is someone who is an ordinary human who controls in some capacity supernatural powers to do supernatural things to accomplish their (the magician’s) will. God is God and doesn’t need to harness powers outside himself—he has all power. So God doing magic doesn’t make sense. When God works miracles, it’s because he’s God and he can.

Also I haven’t read the Pope’s comment so can’t say for sure if I agree with it. That said I do believe that God did speak creation into existence in 6 days, so it sounds like I might disagree with the statement in question assuming I’m understanding it correctly.

How can God be God if he can’t do supernatural things?

When Pope Francis said "God is not a magician" he did not mean that God never does anything beyond the laws of nature. Such a statement would be totally incompatible with Christianity of any form. It was not a categorical statement that God never works miracles, and I think Pope Francis would be appalled that anyone might interpret it that way. In fact, the Pope recognizes that God continues to work miracles into the modern day; I've seen in recent news that the Pope has recognized miracles worked by Carlo Acutis, a vital step in the process of him becoming the first millennial to be canonized as a saint.
The full statement from Pope Francis was

When we read the account of Creation in Genesis we risk imagining that God was a magician, complete with an all powerful magic wand. But that was not so. He created beings and he let them develop according to the internal laws with which He endowed each one, that they might develop, and reach their fullness.

So in context he is discussing Genesis, and in particular Young Earth Creationism - the belief that God created the whole universe recently over the course of six 24-hour days. The Catechism of the Catholic Church (337) states that

God himself created the visible world in all its richness, diversity and order. Scripture presents the work of the Creator symbolically as a succession of six days of divine "work", concluded by the "rest" of the seventh day. On the subject of creation, the sacred text teaches the truths revealed by God for our salvation, permitting us to "recognize the inner nature, the value and the ordering of the whole of creation to the praise of God."

Here, it is clearly affirming both God as creator and the symbolic nature of the six days in the Genesis creation account. Pope Francis's statement is simply reaffirming CCC337, and denying a 'God of the gaps' approach to studying the history of the universe. (This being the anti-scientific response of "God did it" when we cannot imagine how something is possible.) The Pope cannot categorically deny the possibility of supernatural miracles, as Vatican Council I clearly affirms:

If anyone says that all miracles are impossible, and that therefore all reports of them, even those contained in sacred scripture, are to be set aside as fables or myths; or that miracles can never be known with certainty, nor can the divine origin of the Christian religion be proved from them: let him be anathema. (First Vatican Council Decrees, Chapter 3: On Faith, no.4)

Essentially all Christians, Catholic and non-Catholic, agree with both this decree from Vatican I and with CCC337. There are, of course, many Christians understand the six days of creation literally (these being the Young Earth Creationists), but this does not preclude a symbolic meaning as well, and the Catholic Catechism does not indicate that the literal meaning is false. There are also Christians who believe that miracles do not happen any more (these are called cessationists), but they will not deny that the miracles recorded in the Bible such as the virgin birth occurred.
Thus, Christians (including the Pope) believe that the conception of Jesus was supernatural, as the Apostles' Creed states that he "was conceived of the Holy Spirit and born of the Virgin Mary", which clearly states that the conception of Jesus was worked by the Holy Spirit, and that Mary was a
virgin when he was born. As you correctly point out, natural means do not allow for a human virgin to conceive and give birth, so it was necessarily a supernatural event.
How is this different from "imagining that God was a magician, complete with an all-powerful magic wand"? In a sense, it's not. We believe that God is all-powerful. But notice that the Pope said "that was not so" in the context of interpreting Genesis 1. He did not say that God never invokes his omnipotence, nor that God has never superseded the natural laws which he instituted. Rather, the Pope said that God didn't do that in the process of bringing the universe from its initial state until the time of Adam and Eve. The Pope here is voicing the normal opinion of Christian Theistic Evolutionists.

To expand @DarkMalthorps brilliant answer:
Supernatural: Is a characteristic of any event that is not caused by nature or doesn't have natural causes.
=> So how the Bible reports the Birth of Jesus is supernatural.
Magic on the other hand is used differently in the Christian context, compared to the rest of the world:

Magic is the:


"art of influencing or predicting events and producing marvels using hidden natural forces," also "supernatural art," especially the
art of controlling the actions of spiritual or superhuman beings;
etymonline.com


Christianity expands this by also pointing out the source of magic:

Acts 13:6-10:

6 When they had gone through the whole island as far as Paphos, they came upon a certain magician, a Jewish false prophet named Bar-Jesus.
7 He was with the proconsul, Sergius Paulus, a man of intelligence, who summoned Barnabas and Saul and sought to hear the word of God.
8 But Elymas the magician (for that is the meaning of his name) opposed them, seeking to turn the proconsul away from the faith.
9 But Saul, who was also called Paul, filled with the Holy Spirit, looked intently at him
10 and said, “You son of the devil, you enemy of all righteousness, full of all deceit and villainy, will you not stop making crooked the straight paths of the Lord?

=> What that means is that magic (for Christians) always has a demonic or satanic origin. This is clearly not the case in the case of the Birth of Jesus, as the cause of the Birth was God and not the devil.
When referring to supernatural events that have God as their cause, then Christians refer to them as "miracles".
How can God not be a magician if Jesus's conception was supernatural?
=> No, Jesus's conception was miraculous, not magical, as the cause of the Birth was God and not the Devil.
So are there denominations of the Christian Faith that still believe God has unquestionable power?
The Christian Faith is defined by believing in God the Father, Jesus the Son, and the Holy Spirit. So while the the view and concept of power might be nuanced and there might be individuals who might contest the power of God and claim to be Christian, each of the bigger denominations believes God to be powerful.

Also weak mere humans perform magic and feel like they need it to do the supernatural because they’re weak in themselves and can’t do what they want to do. God is God. He’s not weak and he doesn’t need any outside help to do the supernatural. So when he does the supernatural it’s not magic. It’s him being God.

God is all powerful, able to do anything which is not a logical contradiction, including Create humans from nothing, or from dust, or from unfertilized human eggs. God is not bound by the laws of physics, but rather the laws of physics exist because of God's Will. Strictly speaking, when we speak of "natural" and "supernatural", the distinction is not between "types" of powers, but between the ordinary way in which God upholds Creation and the exceptional instances in which God acts contrary to those ordinary ways.
Consider, for example, the most boring person alive, who does exactly the same actions at exactly the same time every day. Those actions would be "natural". Now consider that one day this person receives a phone call that violates this usual routine. That would be "supernatural"... even though the action is not different in kind, but only in that it was not predictable. So, too, God's "supernatural" actions, which are often called "miracles", are merely expressions of His power which are non-ordinary, but are not of a different kind. Thus, the Conception of Jesus doesn't represent an expression of a different kind of power, but only an expression that deviates from "routine".
God's abilities are in no way limited by "nature". Creation — yes, in six synodic days — was supernatural. Noah's Flood, which really happened and left behind ample physical evidence of its historicity, almost certainly was partly supernatural. Jesus conception and resurrection were supernatural. Many other events are recorded in Scripture which were supernatural. Thus, when Pope Francis says "we risk imagining that God was a magician, complete with an all powerful magic wand"... he is wrong. God doesn't use a "wand", but He assuredly is all powerful. Pope Francis, and all those who agree with his (mis)interpretation, are denying the clear teaching of Scripture, as well as God's own words: "in six days [I] the Lᴏʀᴅ made heaven and earth, the sea, and all that is in them" (Exodus 20:11).

Aside: Is God a "magician"? In the Scriptural sense, no. Scripturally, a "magician" is one who seeks to manipulate spiritual powers in order to accomplish supernatural actions. God has granted us the laws of nature in order to accomplish many things, but He reserves the right to work outside those laws for Himself. A magician is, in a sense, an imposter; someone trying to usurp authority that is not rightfully theirs. Since God's Power belongs to Him, God Himself cannot be a "magician" because the idea of usurping that which is His own is nonsense.

"Now consider that one day this person receives a phone call that violates this usual routine. That would be "supernatural"" Isn't that definition a bit open? I mean most people don't consider unusual actions or events supernatural, per se. They only use the word when the event or action is beyond the laws of nature.

@telion, that's what I'm describing. The laws of nature can be broadly conceptualized as "X follows Y", roughly comparable to "at time T, our hypothetical person does X". A violation of routine is compared to a violation of usual cause and effect; e.g. water flows uphill, matter appears from nothing, etc. The routine isn't being compared to actual events, but to the laws of nature themselves. (Maybe placing a phone call would be a better example?) The point of the illustration is that, to God, a "supernatural" event is merely a non-ordinary event.

Because a magician cannot create life while God can. The supernatural conception of Jesus shows us that God has the power and will to create life inside and outside the womb of a woman without natural interventions. If magicians can cause a virgin woman to conceive without natural interventions then they would be comparable , God is not the only source of supernatural wonders, if the power is not coming from God then its coming from the devil and there is no special human being with supernatural abilities. God is aware of magicians and has warned them in advance in the book of Revelation
Revelation 21:8

But as for the cowardly, the faithless, the detestable, as for murderers, the sexually immoral, sorcerers, idolaters, and all liars, their portion will be in the lake that burns with fire and sulfur, which is the second death.”

No magician can cause a woman to conceive supernaturally and we cannot use what man does to define who God is.

I'm not Catholic, but I think a slightly different perspective might also be helpful..

If Mary gave birth to Jesus as a virgin how can this not be considered supernatural as well as in the realm of magic?

I agree with the comments that understanding the definition and differences of "supernatural" and "magic" is necessary to answer your question(s).
According to Google:

magic - "the power of apparently influencing the course of events by using mysterious or supernatural forces."
supernatural - "(of a manifestation or event) attributed to some force beyond scientific understanding or the laws of nature."

Although slightly different from the definition: the way I see it is that "magic" is unexplainable, whereas "supernatural" is explainable, but not yet understood (by us).
My personal belief is that Mary's conception was supernatural (not yet understood), but not magic. I think sometimes we attribute things we don't understand to be "magic" which reminds me of a couple quotes:

“Any sufficiently advanced technology is indistinguishable from magic.” - Arthur C. Clarke


“There is no conflict between science and religion. Conflict only arises from an incomplete knowledge of either science or religion, or both,” Elder Russell M. Nelson of the Quorum of the Twelve Apostles

For your final question:

So are there denominations of the Christian Faith that still believe that God has unquestionable power?

My response would be:

He is the Rock, his work is perfect: for all his ways are judgment: a God of truth and without iniquity, just and right is he. - Deuteronomy 32:4

I believe God is all powerful, but I also think He will only act within what is "just and right". My background and belief comes from The Church of Jesus Christ of Latter-day Saints.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

I'm not certain that I understand the precise implications of the question, but I'll take a shot at it based on my undergraduate studies on this topic. My reflections are indeed non-comprehensive and are informed more by anthropology than theology. In early Christian circles, God is indeed conceived as a sort of magician, and academic arguments can be made that this conception is not a deviation from Levantine conceptions of magic as a divine art. God is an author of miraculous events described in the New Testament. Such miracles, often referred to as "signs" (semeia), "wonders" (terata), "mighty works" (dunameis), or simply "works" (erga), are not consistently defined in the ancient Greek or Hebrew traditions, suggesting a lack of a formal conception of miracles akin to our later understanding of a miracle as "contravention of the laws of nature"  (as we would find in post-Enlightenment times)1. Additionally, observer perceptions of Biblical miracles vary between and among accounts: in the synoptic Gospels, miracles are performed on account of the existing faith of the audience, while in John's Gospel, miracles are employed to elicit faith in those who have not yet been convinced of the Gospel message1 2. However, the Gospels also caution that signs and wonders do not unambiguously prove the sanctity of the miracle worker, warning against false prophets who might use such signs to deceive1. This complex portrayal aligns with the idea that the miraculous acts attributed to God can evoke a sense of wonder similar to that experienced in magic, where the underlying mechanisms are not directly observable and can fashion powerful experiences that appear to elicit conversion to the faith1 2.
Anthropology, particularly the work of Reinhardt3 (2015), offers insights into how contemporary Christian communities perceive and experience the divine through the lenses of immanence and transcendence, which can be akin to understanding magical or supernatural interventions in the natural world3. It is an excellent article if you are interested in bridging philosophy, theology, and ancient history, and it is impressively brief but powerfully argued. This anthropological perspective explores cultural and spiritual contexts that shape how miraculous or magical events are perceived and valued within Christian communities with respect to healing, prophecy, miraculous virgin birth, etc.
References (No Particular Citation Style - #3 is available as a downloadable PDF and was composed at Utrecht University but is written in English. #1 requires a subscription but could be obtained from a research library with sufficient effort).
1 Harrison, Peter. “Miracles, Early Modern Science, and Rational Religion.” Church History 75 (2006): 493 - 510.
2 Ekroll, V., Sayim, B., & Wagemans, J. (2017). The Other Side of Magic: The Psychology of Perceiving Hidden Things. Perspectives on Psychological Science, 12(1), 91-106.
3 Bruno Reinhardt Christian plane of immanence? Contrapuntal reflections on Deleuze and Pentecostal spirituality, Utrecht University 2015 | Hau: Journal of Ethnographic Theory 5 (1): 405–436.
*Clarified and refactored with the assistance of AI. Citations are accurate as of June 2024. The majority of the relevant ideas are cited in #1 and quoted therein. #3 furnishes a theoretical overview.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

I see you received many answers on this question... I do want to clarify for any reading audience that is not privy to the delineation between Catholicism and Christianity, that Catholicism is not Christianity and vise versa, nor do either group identify to be belonging with the other. If they do, then they do not understand their own faith. The difference is in a grace alone (Christian) faith and works-based (Catholicism) faith. Christians believe that the work of Jesus Christ was sufficient at the cross for sins committed in the past, present, and future to save them from their sins and bring them eternal salvation. Conversely, Catholics believe that Christ's work on the cross was not sufficient for eternal salvation and that works, amongst sacraments, are required to qualify for salvation, but purgatory is necessary to cleanse the soul prior to entering Heaven. There's levels to all of this, but this is a short explanation of how these two faiths are not one of the same.

Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and how it is different than others. I would also recommend reading the Help Center's sections on asking and answering questions.

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
